# R DBI just hanging when attempting to connect. No errors

Tags: r

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL Server 2005 db using DBI.

I have an alias for the server name and the database I need. When I input the code;

```
library(DBI) con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             driver = "SQL Server",
             database = "database",
             server = "alias")
```

R hangs indefinitely. I know the alias and database names are correct and I can connect to the database using PowerBI

I've looked at several different guides and tried to use RStudio's connection wizard without any luck.

I'm at a loss without any kind of error to research. Is there anything in my code that would cause it to hang forever?

Thanks for any direction

Comment: You should ask Microsoft about this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known bug:

[R breaks when I state a wrong server in dbConnect() using SQL Server](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/139)